# Pascal half pyramid using array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I am newbie and my problem is that I can't print the pascal half pyramid using array.
I know how to do it without array using this code:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
  for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
    printf("%d ", j);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

When I try to do it using array with the same logic I can't print it out :

```
#define N 11
int main() {
  int pin[N][N];
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
      printf("%d", pin[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I think my fault is this --> `printf("%d" , pin[i][j]);`
But I cant figure it out.

Comment: What value will `pin[i][j]` have when you print it?

Comment: @vapan Your code which does not use an array is also wrong, see what is a [pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle) first.

Comment: Apart from not initializing the matrix, note that array indexing is zero-based in C (and all C-like languages), meaning that your matrix can be correctly accessed for indices `[0][0]` through `[9][9]`. Right now you are accessing (unitinialized) indices `[1][1]` to `[4][4]`. If you're going to have a 5x5 matrix, declare it using `pin[5][5]` and use `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`.

Comment: do you want a pascal triangle or output of first program?

Comment: Sorry the correct is "pascal half pyramid" , i thought that it was the same with the pascal triangle.

Answer (score 0):

In your second program you have no value stored in array `pin`. a simple solution is first store data, the same way, you print it in first program, in array ,then print it.

here in this loop I store data ,which was printed in first program, in `pin` , the only point is since array indexes starts from `0` you starts your loops from `0` too and use `j++` instead of `j`:

```
    int pin[N][N];
    //store data
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i+1 ; ++j)
        {
            pin[i][j] = j + 1;
        }
    }
```

and this is complete code with printing data:

```
#define N 11
int main() {
    int pin[N][N];
    //store data
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            pin[i][j] = j + 1;
        }
    }
    //print data
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%d ", pin[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```